# Need a recommendation on copying data in SQL Server (2008R2)

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, ssis, data-conversion

I have several versions of a single access table which I need to move to a sql server db, which I have built.  What I mean by several versions, there are 6 different schools that built there own access table to track records.  I am consolidating.  The wrinkle is that each location made there table slightly different.

The Access table is like:

Student (StudentId,
StudentName,
StudentAddress,
TeacherId,
TeacherName,
Class1,
Class2,
Class3,
Class4,
Class5,
StudentStatus)

I have built a new database with multiple tables, such as a (this is a rough layout)

Student table (StudentId, FirstName, LastName, TeacherId)

Teacher table (TeacherId, FirstName, LastName)

Class table (ClassId, ClassName, TeacherId)

etc

I imported the access tables to a 'staging' schema in the sql server DB (staging.Location1, staging.Location2, etc).  Now I need to either create an SSIS package to copy the data to the new tables, or write some stored procs. I imagine I will need to do each location individually.

As I stated above, each access table is slightly different, with different datatypes and column names.  For example, one location has the studentID as a varchar and is called StudId, while another location has it as an int and it is called SID, or StudentId, etc.

I can not decide to most efficient route. Am I correct in thinking that either way, this will require at least one SSIS package or SP per location due to the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I say do it this way:

1. Create only one staging table that covers all data you have in those 3 table. Use right data types and field names. Use Identity field as primary key and use a school name as a identifier for each school
2. Copy data from 3 access db into the single staging. do data conversion if needed. This way you will have all data in one place and they are all consistent.
3. Read data from staging and populate the 3 tables you have in your new design. You only need one SSIS package to do this part, you just need to change the destination connection and change the filter on school name

Comment: How would you do the initial load from access to the staging table?  If your doing conversions, would you suggest ssis?

Comment: Yes, The best way to import and conversion is using SSIS